# UISwipeGestureRecognizer - perform action with 2 finger and 3 finger swipe - iOS

Tags: iphone, swap, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How to detect UISwipeGestureRecognizer 2 finger swipe or 3 finger swipe on the same View- iOS

any one have idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here   "setMinimumNumberOfTouches" depends on your fingers(Eg:2/3/4/5). Try it once ..it may help to u

```
  UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
 pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(Swipe4ScrollViews:)];
[pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
 [_scroll1 addGestureRecognizer:pan];
  [pan release];
```

Comment: that's ok, but with UISwipeGestureRecognizer possible if we implement for 2 finger swap and 3 finger..i got it thanks

Answer (score 6):

I have created a gesture for 2 and 3 finger swipe.

```
       func addTwoFingerSwipeGesture() {
            let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTwoFingerSwipe")
            gesture.direction = .Left
            gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2 // 2 finger swipe
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }

       func addThreeFingerSwipeGesture() {
            let gesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleThreeFingerSwipe")
            gesture.direction = .Left
            gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 3 // 3 finger swipe
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }


    // Handle Swipe
        func handleTwoFingerSwipe() {
            print("2 finger swipe recognized")
        }

        func handleThreeFingerSwipe() {
            print("3 finger swipe recognized")
        }
```